# MC34063A switching regulator: LC filter and feedback

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, filter, feedback, stability, mc34063

The MC34063A bust/boost/inverting switching regulator recommends using an LC filter at the output, after the filtering cap. This LC filter is optional and there is no mention in the data sheet about including it in the feedback loop. I'm tempted on including the filter in the loop but maybe I'm risking the stability for a small return of some small fraction of volt for the higher currents (and the currents won't be more than 0.5A)

Could it be detrimental in terms of stability? Has anyone tried this with this regulator?

Comment: Realistically the properly designed LC filter should have almost no effect on DC. If you're concerned about resistive losses, just get a slightly oversized inductor to reduce its DC resistance. I would be concerned about putting it in the feedback loop, it will create a huge phase shift.

Comment: The phase shift and stability were my main concerns. I'll check the oversized inductor route if and when necessary. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [switching regulator output filtering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/477092/switching-regulator-output-filtering)

Comment: Not exactly. I saw that one before posting and in that regulator they have a section explicitly talking about stability and how to select the components to keep the loop stable. Since I saw no mention at all about stability in the MC34063 data sheet I was assuming it was very difficult to make it unstable and maybe I could get away... Thank you though, Andy.

Answer (score 1):

The TI datasheet does show the extra filter. It is out of the feedback loop, as one would in general expect.

Comment: I have probably misinterpreted it. They called them both Vout, with the feedback formula on the second one. Maybe it should be Vout and Vout' since it's not the same net even the voltage will be practically identical under some conditions. That triggered my thinking into removing any IR drop in the inductor, like you would do in any OpAmp and checked if it was done in switching regulators. Obviously it can be done but it involves some analysis that is way more complex than the design with this regulator which is almost trivial. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Realistically the properly designed LC filter should have almost no effect on DC. If you're concerned about resistive losses, just get a slightly oversized inductor to reduce its DC resistance. I would be concerned about putting it in the feedback loop, it will create a huge phase shift.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I design something like that I do 2 things:
-write a simulation.  Takes some effort, but you will learn a lot.  Matlab, octave, or python will do it.
-after you have the supply working, put a transient load on it (with a resistor, mosfet, and pulse generator) and observe the transient response.  Again, takes some effort, but the difference between your simulation and the real world may be highly entertaining!

Comment: The supply is just a module in a bigger project and I don't really want to spend so long in such issue. I had the suspicion that including the filter wasn't a good idea and I won't risk it since there is much to lose (including time and effort!) and little to win. The problem with simulation is that unless your model is accurate enough the results could be misleading. I would definitely simulate it if I had a simulation model from the manufacturer or if everything was discrete. I'm curious now though; why and how would you model the regulator in matlab or python, as opposed to in LTSPICE?

Comment: Sure, LTSPICE or NGSPICE can be used.  For Octave the daspk module is very helpful.  In python you can use any one of the ode solvers in scipy, or what I used a few times was scikits.odes.  You don't have to simulate all the way down to the component level.  For loop stability problems like this I like to simplify, linearize things, write out the differential equations, and pick the filter components to give me good step response with no ringing.  If your step response in this approximation turns out to be faster than your switching frequency, go back and slow things down.

Comment: Thanks electrogas, I might try this approach with differential equations (or Laplace) in future designs.